# Slowness of first file upload to library on SP2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019

We have a strange behavior on our new 2019 SP farm. The first file upload to library is very slow.
Subsequent request are much faster (400K file in first upload takes 3 seconds the next upload takes 0.5s)
This is on already warmed up app via UI. (we checked the usual culprits and we had the revocation issue happening as well) that helped to a degree but this issue still persists.

The only error (unexpected event) I can see in the ULS is this related to Cobolt:

> RecordStreamStorageOperationResult unable to log due to missing
> SPSuppIementaIInstrumentation

Googling it doesn´t bring nothing useful so far. Has anyone faced this event before and can shed some light on it?

Comment: For repro purposes, what file type(s) are involved? Is this via modern UI or classic UI?

Comment: During the testing we are uploading 2 types of files pdf and zip via modern UI.